# how to get all the words that start with a letter in a datatable?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010 in spanish. I have this:

```
private sub filter(byval letter as char)
Dim arrayrows() As DataRow
arrayrows = table.Select("desc_ Art like '" + letter + "%'")
end sub
```

So when the parameter "letter" is "a" I get the rows where desc_art starts with "a". The problem is when the parameter "letter" is  "c" I don´t get words that second letter is "h". It's like the program thinks that "ch" is a letter.

How can I get all the words who's first letter is "c"?

Comment: It is possible to do with the collation order of the database. If it is Spanish then words starting with Ch come under h.

Comment: Is the column a Char or an NChar?

Comment: It´s a varchar. The SQL statement in console returns what i want but in visual studio no.

Comment: Try declaring it as NVarChar, then the column will be stored as unicode so you shouldn't have collation issues on the column.

Answer (score 1):

the "letter" parameters is declared as a char, have you tried declaring as a string?

Comment: It does the same. But it´s fine. Thanks.